# JPanel to Printpreview

Tags: java, swing, printing, jpanel

I have the PrintPrew class

```
    import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.print.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class PrintPrew extends JFrame implements ActionListener, ChangeListener, ItemListener {

    JButton print = new JButton("Print"),
            cancel = new JButton("Close");
    Pageable pg = null;
    double scale = 1.0;
    JSlider slider = new JSlider();
    Page page[] = null;
    JComboBox jcb = new JComboBox();
    CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();
    JPanel p = new JPanel(cl);


    public PrintPrew(final Printable pr, final PageFormat p) {
        super("Предпросмотр");
        this.pg = new Pageable() {
            public int getNumberOfPages() {
                Graphics g = new java.awt.image.BufferedImage(2,2,java.awt.image.BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB).getGraphics();
                int n=0;
                try { while(pr.print(g, p, n) == pr.PAGE_EXISTS) n++; }
                catch(Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
                return n;
            }
            public PageFormat getPageFormat(int x) { return p; }
            public Printable getPrintable(int x) { return pr; }
        };
        createPreview();
    }

    private void createPreview() {
        page = new Page[pg.getNumberOfPages()];
        FlowLayout fl = new FlowLayout();
        PageFormat pf = pg.getPageFormat(0);
        Dimension size = new Dimension((int)pf.getPaper().getWidth(), (int)pf.getPaper().getHeight());
        if(pf.getOrientation() != PageFormat.PORTRAIT)
            size = new Dimension(size.height, size.width);
        JPanel temp = null;
        for(int i=0; i<page.length; i++) {
            jcb.addItem(""+(i+1));
            page[i] = new Page(i, size);
            p.add(""+(i+1), new JScrollPane(page[i]));
        }
        setTopPanel();
        this.getContentPane().add(p, "Center");
        Dimension d = this.getToolkit().getScreenSize();
        this.setSize(d.width,d.height-60);
        slider.setSize(this.getWidth()/2, slider.getPreferredSize().height);
        this.setVisible(true);
        page[jcb.getSelectedIndex()].refreshScale();
    }

    private void setTopPanel() {
        FlowLayout fl = new FlowLayout();
        GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel(gbl), temp = new JPanel(fl); slider.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Percentage Zoom"));
        slider.setPaintTicks(true);
        slider.setPaintLabels(true);
        slider.setMinimum(0);
        slider.setMaximum(500);
        slider.setValue(100);
        slider.setMinorTickSpacing(20);
        slider.setMajorTickSpacing(100);
        slider.addChangeListener(this);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbl.setConstraints(slider, gbc);
        topPanel.add(slider);
        temp.add(jcb);
        temp.add(cancel);
        temp.add(print);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        gbl.setConstraints(temp, gbc);
        topPanel.add(temp);
        print.addActionListener(this);
        cancel.addActionListener(this);
        jcb.addItemListener(this);
        print.setMnemonic('P');
        cancel.setMnemonic('C');
        this.getContentPane().add(topPanel, "North");
    }




    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        Object o = ae.getSource();
        if(o == print) {
            try {
                PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
                pj.defaultPage(pg.getPageFormat(0));
                pj.setPageable(pg);
                if(pj.printDialog())
                    pj.print();
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex.toString(), "Error in Printing",1);
            }
        }
        else if(o == cancel) this.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent ce) {
        double temp = (double)slider.getValue()/100.0;
        if(temp == scale)
            return;
        if(temp == 0) temp = 0.01;
        scale = temp;
        page[jcb.getSelectedIndex()].refreshScale();
        this.validate();
    }

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie) {
        cl.show(p, (String)jcb.getSelectedItem());
        page[jcb.getSelectedIndex()].refreshScale();
        this.validate();
    }

    public void printCurrentPage() {
        try {
            PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
            pj.defaultPage(pg.getPageFormat(0));
            pj.setPrintable(new PsuedoPrintable());
            javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet pra =
                    new javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
            if(pj.printDialog(pra))
                pj.print(pra);
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex.toString(), "Error in Printing", 1);
        }
    }

    class Page extends JLabel {
        final int n;
        final PageFormat pf;
        java.awt.image.BufferedImage bi = null;
        Dimension size = null;
        public Page(int x, Dimension size) {
            this.size = size;
            bi = new java.awt.image.BufferedImage(size.width, size.height, java.awt.image.BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            n = x;
            pf = pg.getPageFormat(n);
            Graphics g = bi.getGraphics();
            Color c = g.getColor();
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, (int)pf.getWidth(), (int)pf.getHeight());
            g.setColor(c);
            try {
                g.clipRect(0, 0, (int)pf.getWidth(), (int)pf.getHeight());
                pg.getPrintable(n).print(g, pf, n);
            }
            catch(Exception ex) { }
            this.setIcon(new ImageIcon(bi));
        } public void refreshScale() {
            if(scale != 1.0)
                this.setIcon(new ImageIcon(bi.getScaledInstance((int)(size.width*scale), (int)(size.height*scale), bi.SCALE_FAST)));
            else
                this.setIcon(new ImageIcon(bi));
            this.validate();
        }
    }

    class PsuedoPrintable implements Printable {
        public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat fmt, int index) {
            if(index > 0) return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
            int n = jcb.getSelectedIndex();
            try { return pg.getPrintable(n).print(g, fmt, n); }
            catch(Exception ex) {}
            return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
        }
    }

}
```

and my Jpanel class, which I want to print

```
public class NewJPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel implements Printable {

    /**
     * Creates new form NewJPanel
     */
    public NewJPanel() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel10 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel11 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jLabel12 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel13 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel14 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel15 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel16 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jInternalFrame1 = new javax.swing.JInternalFrame();
        jInternalFrame2 = new javax.swing.JInternalFrame();
        jInternalFrame3 = new javax.swing.JInternalFrame();
        jInternalFrame4 = new javax.swing.JInternalFrame();
        jLabel17 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        jLabel1.setText("Накладная №");

        jLabel2.setText("Марка авто");

        jLabel3.setText("Предприятие");

        jLabel4.setText("jLabel4");

        jLabel5.setText("jLabel5");

        jLabel6.setText("Номер авто");

        jLabel7.setText("jLabel7");

        jLabel8.setText("Водитель");

        jLabel9.setText("jLabel9");

        jLabel10.setText("Документ №");

        jLabel11.setText("jLabel11");

        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
            }
        ));
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

        jLabel12.setText("Примечание");

        jLabel13.setText("jLabel13");

        jLabel14.setText("Оператор");

        jLabel15.setText("jLabel15");

        jLabel16.setText("Подпись __________");

        jInternalFrame1.setVisible(true);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jInternalFrame1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jInternalFrame1.getContentPane());
        jInternalFrame1.getContentPane().setLayout(jInternalFrame1Layout);
        jInternalFrame1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jInternalFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 60, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jInternalFrame1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jInternalFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jInternalFrame2.setVisible(true);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jInternalFrame2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jInternalFrame2.getContentPane());
        jInternalFrame2.getContentPane().setLayout(jInternalFrame2Layout);
        jInternalFrame2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jInternalFrame2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 73, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jInternalFrame2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jInternalFrame2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jInternalFrame3.setVisible(true);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jInternalFrame3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jInternalFrame3.getContentPane());
        jInternalFrame3.getContentPane().setLayout(jInternalFrame3Layout);
        jInternalFrame3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jInternalFrame3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 79, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jInternalFrame3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jInternalFrame3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jInternalFrame4.setVisible(true);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jInternalFrame4Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jInternalFrame4.getContentPane());
        jInternalFrame4.getContentPane().setLayout(jInternalFrame4Layout);
        jInternalFrame4Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jInternalFrame4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 86, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jInternalFrame4Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jInternalFrame4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 207, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jLabel17.setText("jLabel17");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel12)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(jLabel13, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 279, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addContainerGap(14, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel14)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(jLabel15)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel16, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 108, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(27, 27, 27))))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(89, 89, 89)
                                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                .addComponent(jLabel17, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 97, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(21, 21, 21)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                                .addGap(19, 19, 19)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                            .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 67, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                            .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 67, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                        .addGap(36, 36, 36)
                                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                            .addComponent(jLabel6)
                                            .addComponent(jLabel8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING))
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                            .addComponent(jLabel7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 70, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                            .addComponent(jLabel9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 109, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                                    .addComponent(jLabel11))))
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jInternalFrame1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(jInternalFrame2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(jInternalFrame3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(jInternalFrame4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(31, 31, 31)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jLabel17))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                    .addComponent(jLabel6)
                    .addComponent(jLabel7))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5)
                    .addComponent(jLabel8)
                    .addComponent(jLabel9))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 14, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel11))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 97, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel12)
                    .addComponent(jLabel13))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel14)
                    .addComponent(jLabel15)
                    .addComponent(jLabel16))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jInternalFrame4)
                    .addComponent(jInternalFrame2)
                    .addComponent(jInternalFrame1)
                    .addComponent(jInternalFrame3))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
    }// </editor-fold>                        


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JInternalFrame jInternalFrame1;
    private javax.swing.JInternalFrame jInternalFrame2;
    private javax.swing.JInternalFrame jInternalFrame3;
    private javax.swing.JInternalFrame jInternalFrame4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel10;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel11;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel12;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel13;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel14;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel15;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel16;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel17;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    // End of variables declaration   


@Override
    public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) graphics;
        if (pageIndex >= 1) {
            return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        } else {

            this.printAll(g2);
            return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
        }
    }

}
```

But if I use my printPrew for my NewJPanel its or don`t visualise nothing or just white list for printing.

What I need to change?

When I use my printPeview in other program with table, its work, but in this program whis same table this just draw some lines....

Comment: You should use something like Jasper Reports - the `JScrollPane` alone is going to give you no end of head aches

Comment: Since `NewJPanel` doesn't implement `Printable`, how do you generate the print preview of it?

Comment: add part with ovveride print